# Currency Converter with JSONp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsonp

I am having difficulty with JSONP and my currency converter I am trying to build. I am assuming it is something so simple as I am still very new at programming, etc.

I have HTML in which the user can enter the number in which they want to convert, and select the from and two currencies. When they click convert, there is a loading message that displays, but nothing else ever happens. Any and all help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('#btnConvert').click(function() {

$('#result').html('Loading...');

var amount = $('#amount').val();
var from = $('#from').val();
var to = $('#to').val();

$.ajax({ type: "GET",
    url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?$from"+from+"&to="+to+"&q="+amount+"",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function() {
        $('#result').html();
    }
});
});
});
```

Here is the body section of my HTML:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <table>
 <tr><td align="right">Enter Amount:</td><td>  <input id="amount" maxlength="12" size="5" value="1" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td align="right">From:</td><td>
<select id="from">
<option value="AED">United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)</option>
<option value="ANG">Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)</option>
<option value="BWP">Botswanan Pula (BWP)</option>
<option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar (HKD)</option>
<option value="HNL">Honduran Lempira (HNL)</option>
<option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna (HRK)</option>
<option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint (HUF)</option>
<option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah (IDR)</option>
<option value="ILS">Israeli New Sheqel (ILS)</option>
<option value="MAD">Moroccan Dirham (MAD)</option>
<option value="MDL">Moldovan Leu (MDL)</option>
<option value="MKD">Macedonian Denar (MKD)</option>
<option value="MUR">Mauritian Rupee (MUR)</option>
<option value="MVR">Maldivian Rufiyaa (MVR)</option>
<option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option>
<option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit (MYR)</option>
<option value="NAD">Namibian Dollar (NAD)</option>
<option value="TTD">Trinidad and Tobago Dollar (TTD)</option>
<option value="TWD">New Taiwan Dollar (TWD)</option>
<option value="TZS">Tanzanian Shilling (TZS)</option>
<option value="UAH">Ukrainian Hryvnia (UAH)</option>
<option value="UGX">Ugandan Shilling (UGX)</option>
<option value="USD" selected>US Dollar (USD)</option>

</select></td>
</tr>
<tr> <td align="right">to:</td><td>
<select id="to">
<option value="AED">United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)</option>
<option value="ANG">Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)</option>
<option value="ARS">Argentine Peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="AUD">Australian Dollar (AUD)</option>
<option value="EGP">Egyptian Pound (EGP)</option>
<option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
<option value="FJD">Fijian Dollar (FJD)</option>
<option value="GBP">British Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
<option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar (HKD)</option>
<option value="HNL">Honduran Lempira (HNL)</option>
<option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna (HRK)</option>
<option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint (HUF)</option>
<option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah (IDR)</option>
<option value="ILS">Israeli New Sheqel (ILS)</option>
<option value="INR" selected>Indian Rupee (INR)</option>
<option value="JMD">Jamaican Dollar (JMD)</option>
<option value="JOD">Jordanian Dinar (JOD)</option>
<option value="JPY">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="MVR">Maldivian Rufiyaa (MVR)</option>
<option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option>
<option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit (MYR)</option>
<option value="NAD">Namibian Dollar (NAD)</option>
<option value="NGN">Nigerian Naira (NGN)</option>
<option value="NIO">Nicaraguan Córdoba (NIO)</option>
<option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone (NOK)</option>
<option value="NPR">Nepalese Rupee (NPR)</option>
<option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar (NZD)</option>
<option value="OMR">Omani Rial (OMR)</option>
<option value="PEN">Peruvian Nuevo Sol (PEN)</option>
<option value="PGK">Papua New Guinean Kina (PGK)</option>
<option value="PHP">Philippine Peso (PHP)</option>
<option value="PKR">Pakistani Rupee (PKR)</option>
<option value="PLN">Polish Zloty (PLN)</option>
<option value="PYG">Paraguayan Guarani (PYG)</option>
<option value="QAR">Qatari Rial (QAR)</option>
<option value="RON">Romanian Leu (RON)</option>
<option value="RSD">Serbian Dinar (RSD)</option>

</select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td> <input id="btnConvert" type="button" value="Convert"  style="padding:5px;      10px;"/></td></tr>
</table>
<div >
<div id="result" style="padding: 2px; margin: 5px; font-size:20pt">
</div>
</div>
<br />
</form>


<!-- jQuery hosted by google version 2.0.3-->    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="test_2.js"></script>
```

---

Update: I think I am getting somewhere! When I use the developer tools, the get URL is now correct... but it is still not working. Blah
           $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnConvert').click(function () {

```
        $('#result').html('Loading...');

    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();
    var value = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&q=" + amount + "&callback=success",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        cache: true,
        success: function success(resp) {
            $('#result').html(resp.v);

        }
    });
});
});
```

---

---

Another Update - As I am getting somewhere...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnConvert').click(function () {

    $('#result').html('Loading...');

    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();




    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&q=" + amount + "&callback=function",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        cache: true,
        success: function(resp) {
            document.getElementById('#result').innerHtml=resp.v;
        }


    });
});
});
```

So when I test it out, I do get a response of (in Developer Tools):
    function({"to": "EUR", "rate": 0.72894899999999996, "from": "USD", "v": 0.72894899999999996})

Which is what I want, but I don't know how to display "v"... I have been trying resp.v or data.v but it won't show...

Comment: Firebug is your friend, so you can watch requests go out and return, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your ajax function should look like -

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from="+from+"&to="+to+"&q="+amount,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(resp) {
        $('#result').html(resp.v);
    }
});
```

You should not specify the callback function name in the URL. Jquery will do that automatically.

Comment: Well that is just silly! Is 'resp' supposed to mean something. I changed my success function to exactly how you show it, and it is still just loading... and loading...

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got an extra character in there making your request invalid: `?$from` should be `?from`.

`html()` with no arguments only gets the html, you're not setting it to anything. Try this:

```
success: function(resp) {
    $('#result').html(resp.v);
}
```

If that's not the right way to get the [`v` property](http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=GBP&q=10) out of `resp`, try `resp["v"]` or something.

Comment: Still not working :( 

I have tried exactly what you said to do, and it didn't work. I also tried using data.v, data.[v], data.["v"] and I couldn't get it.

Comment: Have you tried as Mark suggested and use Firebug to try to debug this? If so and you're still stuck, let us know what you find.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see his response. I am using the developer tools with Chrome to try and debug it...

I get this error message:
    GET http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1  jquery.js:7845
    x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send jquery.js:7845
    x.extend.ajax jquery.js:7301
    (anonymous function) test_2.js:10
    x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676
    y.handle

Answer (score 0):

This is fine.You can try this......

```
$('#result').val('Loading...');

var amount = $('#amount').val();
var from = $('#from').val();
var to = $('#to').val();



 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
       url: "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=" + from + "_" + to +"&compact=y",
    success: function(data) {
        var exchangeRate = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

        var result = amount*exchangeRate;
           $('#result').val(parseFloat(result).toFixed(2));
        }
    });

});
```